# Changing the class of an element in JqueryUI sortable while maintaining sortability

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using JqueryUI to sort a nested set of `ol` and `li` elements in a tree.  I have also placed empty `ol` elements at each leaf node so that children can be added to the leaf nodes.

Currently the empty place holders display all the time and work fine.  However I want to hide them until I start sorting the `ul` and `li` elements.
By using Jquery I can change the css class of the empty elements to show and hide them as needed (borders and heights added or removed).  I've wired these up to the `start` and `stop` events in `.sortable`, this showing/hidding also works.

However, the place holders no longer work as areas that will accept other sortable elements.

How can I fix this so the place holders still work as valid droppable areas after they have had their classes changed.

N.B I did preserve the `ui-sortable` class of the place holder elements.

Thanks.

Code:

```
$(".sitemapList").sortable(
{
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight1",
    distance: 5,
    connectWith: ".sitemapList", 
    start: function (event, ui)
    {         
        var change = $(".dontShow");
        var length = change.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            $(change[i]).attr("class", "sitemapList show ui-sortable");
        }
    },
    stop: function (event, ui)
    {
        var change = $(".show");
        var length = change.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            $(change[i]).attr("class", "sitemapList dontShow ui-sortable");
        }
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
    .siteMap ol.show  
     {
        min-height:28px;
        width:15%;
        /*background-color:#f7eac9;*/
        border:dotted 1px;
     }

    .siteMap ol.dontShow
     {
     }
```

Comment: It would be easier if you could post some code

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

http://mjsarfatti.com/sandbox/nestedSortable/

Comment: I already have the nested sort-able list.  However when I change a css class of one of the elements to effect its size and border it stops being sort-able.

Comment: Make sure your sortable event is initialized after the you add this class as well. Maybe that will help